# React material ui table won't stretch to fill

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm experimenting with my own virtualization by using an example (rather than react-virtualized) and I'm having issues with styling

Can anyone tell me why the material table in the code sandbox below won't stretch to fit it's paper component? I'm sure there's a CSS property I need to set somewhere but I'm not sure what it is

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-virtualization-c8tys

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an example for you. I think is something what you are looking for.

I added a custom class `DataTable-tableWrapper-3` with `display: table` and I make each row with `display: inline-table` and `width: 100%` .

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-virtualization-h1c2e

Comment: Ah sweet! Nice one. Thank you so much :) Just a question - I can't see how DataTable-tableWrapper-3 is getting applied. Can you explain?

Comment: Yea, sure. I added custom class in `styles.css` with !important. But If you don't want to do that you can change the value of display from `flex` to `table` in the `tableWrapper` key in DataTable.js. It should be work. Here is an another example. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-virtualization-p431e

Answer (score -1):

This is not really related to React, but more to how you structure and style the table using `html` and `css`.

Why not just use the `width: 100%;` `css` rule on your `table` element? This would give your the result you want:

```css
table {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

table tr {
  height: 37px;
}

table thead {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

table
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>Marie</td>
      <td>Curie</td>
      <td>66</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>Tesler</td>
      <td>75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Sheldon</td>
      <td>Cooper</td>
      <td>35</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```